# PHP & MySQL best practice - creating different views for admin and user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a web app with two types of users, lecturers (admins) and students(users). Most of the pages should have same HTML structure.
Currently, I have two tables with almost the same structure, `lecturers` and `users`. The difference is two columns that users have and admins don't (date_begin_studying and dob).

So my questions are..

- Is this the right way to structure the DB?.  assume that the login page should be same one for both types but than should i query one table and if false than query the other one?
- And after login should i create different pages for each one or should i use the same page and change the content by the type of the logged in user?

Any other conclusions from more experienced users will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should have three or more user type. Administrators are the ones who have control over application. In future you may have to create a dashboard for maintaining your application.

Answer (score 0):

The login page should be the same for both types but I would set the user id's and passwords in the database themselves. You can do that without a conditional statement.

Have two different tables for lecturers and users yes, and create a login form checking to see which user id (email) and passwords match from checking both tables. Then set a conditional statement echoing the data only meant for users to see.

As for your second question, I'd keep to one page and change the content based on whether the user or lecturer is logged in. This can be checked via user session using `isset()`.